# the_title() & the_content() are retrieving Post details inside a Page, after calling a shortcode

Tags: php, shortcode

I'm trying to create a custom theme, since I need to convert html pages to be used at WordPress.

In about.php **page**, I have this **shortcode** to retrieve **posts** of a category:

`<?php echo do_shortcode('[categoryposts catname="about-section-1"]'); ?>`

**functions.php**:

```php
 function wpb_postsbycategory($atts='') {

    // Get parameters\attributes from shortcode
    $attributes = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'catname' => '',//this is default value
        ),
        $atts,
        'featured'
    );

   // the query
   $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
       'category_name' => $attributes['catname'], 
       'posts_per_page' => 5
   ) );
      
   // The Loop
   $string = "";
   if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
       $string .= '<ul class="postsbycategory widget_recent_entries">';
       while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
           $the_query->the_post();
               if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    $string .= '<li>';
                    $string .= '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, array( 50, 50) ) . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
               } else { 
                    // if no featured image is found
                    $string .= '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
               }
            }
    } else {
        // no posts found
        $string .= '<li>No Posts Found</li>';
   }
   $string .= '</ul>';
      
   return $string;
      
   /* Restore original Post Data */
   wp_reset_postdata();
 }
 // Add a shortcode
 add_shortcode('categoryposts', 'wpb_postsbycategory');
```

Though about.php is a PAGE (since I linked it using Template Name), if I use **the_title() & the_content()**:

- **before** the shortcode line, they properly get current **Page** title & content.
- but **after** the shortcode line, they wrongly get some **Post** title & content.

**Question**:
**How can I retrieve Page title & content (instead of Post), after having used shortcode**? Do I need some reset functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I need some reset functionality?

**Yes, you do** — when you call `$the_query->the_post()`, the global `$post` variable will be modified so that the `the_` functions like `the_title()`, `the_content()` and `the_permalink()` will use the current post in your custom loop, and thus after the loop ends, you should call [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/) in order to restore the `$post` global to the current post in the main query (that's referenced via the global `$wp_query` variable), because otherwise then the issue in question would happen.

And your code/function is actually calling `wp_reset_postdata()`, except that it never got called because it's called after the `return` line, i.e. you did `return $string; wp_reset_postdata();`..

So you would just need to swap their position, like so:

```php
wp_reset_postdata(); // call this first

return $string;      // then return the output
```

But I would probably call the function right after the `while` block ends, i.e. `while ( ... ) { ... } wp_reset_postdata();`, because there's nothing to reset if the `$the_query->the_post()` didn't run.

Additionally, the `$post_id` as in `get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, array( 50, 50) )` is never defined in your code, so you should change that to `get_the_ID()`, or use `null` instead to use the current post in your loop.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain. You're a great girl\guy. Virtual hugs.